# What is the 'function' keyword used in some bash scripts?

Tags: bash

For example:
[Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-8.html)

```
function foo() {}
```

I make search queries in `info bash` and look in releted chapters of POSIX for **function** keyword but nothing found.

What is `function` keyword used in some bash scripts? Is that some deprecated syntax?

Answer (score 140, accepted):

The `function` keyword is optional when defining a function in Bash, as documented in the [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Functions):

> Functions are declared using this syntax:
>
> `name () compound-command [ redirections ]`
>
> or
>
> `function name [()] compound-command [ redirections ]`

The first form of the syntax is generally preferred because it's compatible with Bourne/Korn/POSIX scripts and so more portable.
That said, sometimes you might want to use the `function` keyword to prevent Bash [aliases](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Aliases) from colliding with your function's name. Consider this example:

```
$ alias foo="echo hi"
$ foo() { :; }
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Here, `'foo'` is replaced by the text of the alias of the same name because it's the *first word* of the command. With `function` the alias is not expanded:

```
 $ function foo() { :; }
```

Comment: @gavenkoa [Yes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29). When using the 'function' keyword, Bash function declarations are not compatible with Bourne/Korn/POSIX scripts.

Comment: Note that in Korn shell there are differences in the scope of `typedef`'ed variables between the two ways of declaring functions (since scoped variables are not POSIX).

Comment: How would you differentiate between a call to the `foo` alias and the `foo` function?

Comment: @AaronFranke You can use the `type` built-in, e.g. `type -a foo`.

Comment: If you don't care about Bourne/Korn/POSIX scripts, you should declare the bash function with `function function_name`

Answer (score 84):

The `function` keyword is necessary in rare cases when the function name is also an alias.  Without it, Bash expands the alias before parsing the function definition -- probably not what you want:

```
alias mycd=cd
mycd() { cd; ls; }  # Alias expansion turns this into cd() { cd; ls; }
mycd                # Fails. bash: mycd: command not found
cd                  # Uh oh, infinite recursion.
```

With the `function` keyword, things work as intended:

```
alias mycd=cd
function mycd() { cd; ls; }  # Defines a function named mycd, as expected.
cd                           # OK, goes to $HOME.
mycd                         # OK, goes to $HOME.
\mycd                        # OK, goes to $HOME, lists directory contents.
```

Answer (score 13):

The reserved word `function` is optional. See the section 'Shell Function Definitions' in the [bash man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash).