# Bash script error: "function: not found". Why would this appear?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, ubuntu, terminal

I'm trying to run a `bash script` on my Ubuntu machine and it is giving me an error:

> function not found

To test, I created the following script which works fine on my laptop but not on my Desktop.  Any ideas as to why?  My laptop is a mac if that's relevant.

```
#!/bin/bash

function sayIt {   
   echo "hello world"
}

sayIt
```

This returns "hello world" on my laptop, but on my Desktop it returns:

> run.sh: 3: function not found  hello world   run.sh: 5: Syntax error:
>   "}" unexpected

Comment: It would be interesting to know how you called the script.

Answer (score 163):

Chances are that on your desktop you are not actually running under `bash` but rather `dash` or some other POSIX-compliant shell that does not recognize the `function` keyword.  The `function` keyword is a bashism, a bash extension.  POSIX syntax does not use `function` and mandates the use of parenthesis.

```
$ more a.sh
#!/bin/sh

function sayIt {   
   echo "hello world"
}

sayIt
$ bash a.sh
hello world
$ dash a.sh
a.sh: 3: function: not found
hello world
a.sh: 5: Syntax error: "}" unexpected
```

The POSIX-syntax works in both:

```
$ more b.sh
#!/bin/sh

sayIt () {   
   echo "hello world"
}

sayIt
$ bash b.sh
hello world
$ dash b.sh
hello world
```

Comment: `function` comes from the korn shell, which pre-dates bash.

Comment: +1 Had this exact problem, but the bash would still perform as expected. At least with your explanation I know the **why** and **how**! :)

Comment: So, how to run a script under bash instead of dash or POSIX-compliant shell?

Comment: A likely cause is that the script doesn't have the execute bit set for the executing user, meaning that it's being read as a plain shell script.  Make sure that's correct and that the shebang path actually invokes Bash.

Comment: For me, i was running a sh script (e.g. _sh train.sh -d_) but it gave me the error. This answer helped me to realise the problem (i had to write _/bin/bash train.sh -d_ instead)

Comment: "Chances are that on your desktop you are not actually running under bash". If the first line is /bin/bash, IT IS running under bash I suppose. But: if you start the script with sh .., sh will probably dominate. So you have to start it with ./script.sh in order to "use" the frist shebang line. Thus: It would be interesting to know how op called the script.

Comment: also note that function needs to be defined before use

Answer (score 28):

I faced the same problem, I then modified the syntax and it worked for me. Try to **remove** the keyword ***function*** and *add **brackets ()*** after the function name.

```
#!/bin/bash

sayIt()
{   
   echo "hello world"
}

sayIt
```

Comment: This is not the ideal solution as both syntaxes are defined but your syntax is used for /bin/sh scripts while `function name { ... }` is used for e.g. /bin/bash. So the OP is probably using the wrong interpreter (She-Bang line says it should be bash, but that line is ignored if you explicitly start the script using `sh ...`)

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! for that info!

Answer (score 9):

ls -la /bin/sh

check the sym link where it point to bash or dash

Comment: why would #!/bin/bash not take care of this?

Answer (score -2):

For me, I just edited the bash profile and forgot to **restart** my terminal session.

Answer (score -5):

Doesn't it require () after function name, or at the call?

```
function sayIt() { ...
}

sayIt()
```

? :)

Hmm, actually, on MY mac, it works just as you pasted..

```
dtpwmbp:~ pwadas$ cat aa.sh 
#!/bin/bash

function sayIt() {   
   echo "hello world"
}

sayIt

dtpwmbp:~ pwadas$ ./aa.sh 
hello world
dtpwmbp:~ pwadas$
```

Compare bash version, AFAIR some older version required "()"s.

```
dtpwmbp:~ pwadas$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.48(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin12)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
dtpwmbp:~ pwadas$
```

Also compare state of shopt options ( man bash ), on both shells, maybe one of them have some compat syntax turned on or off ? "shopt" command without args will list state of options supported.

[What is the 'function' keyword used in some bash scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7917018/what-is-the-function-keyword-used-in-some-bash-scripts)

Comment: Sadly, I really don't know why my answer for this question was downvoted :/

Comment: You should include the `()` in the function definition but not when calling the function.

Comment: @PiotrWadas, I didn't downvote you, but it's really more of a question than an answer.

Comment: yea, your answer is really a question about the answer above. so it should be a comment on that answer and not an answer itself

Comment: `function foo() {` is actually **more** invalid than `function foo {`. The `function foo {` syntax is supported on old versions of ksh, and modern shells that try to maintain compatibility with them, but **not** required to be supported by shells compliant with the 1992 POSIX sh standard. By contrast, `foo() {` is valid on all POSIX-compliant shells. `function foo() {` is a hybrid of the two formats, and less widely supported than either on its own. See http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete