# Defining a UNIX Alias And/Or Function with Awk and ifconfig

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, awk

I have the following command which displays to me my current IP address:

```
ifconfig -a | awk 'BEGIN { count=0; } { if ( $1 ~ /inet/ ) { count++; if( count==2 ) { print $2; } } }'
```

I'd like to be able to wrap this command into an alias such as:

```
alias myip="ifconfig -a | awk 'BEGIN { count=0; } { if ( $1 ~ /inet/ ) { count++; if( count==2 ) { print $2; } } }'"
```

or even a function like so:

```
function myip() { ifconfig -a | awk 'BEGIN { count=0; } { if ( $1 ~ /inet/ ) { count++; if( count==2 ) { print $2; } } }' }
```

However, none of these solutions work and I get this error:

```
syntax error near unexpected token ``{ifconfig'
```

I've tried this:

```
alias myip='ifconfig -a | awk '\''BEGIN{ count=0; } { if ( $1 ~ /inet/ ) { count++; if( count==2 ) { print $2; } } }'\'''
```

but no luck.

How would I be able to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Your function needs a `;` before the closing `}`

```
function myip() { ifconfig -a | awk 'BEGIN { count=0; } { if ( $1 ~ /inet/ ) { count++; if( count==2 ) { print $2; } } }'; }
                                                                                                                  HERE --^
```

2) You only need either `function` or `()`, but [not both](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7917018/what-is-the-function-keyword-used-in-some-bash-scripts).  (Although this depends on your shell.)

```
function myip { ifconfig -a | awk 'BEGIN { count=0; } { if ( $1 ~ /inet/ ) { count++; if( count==2 ) { print $2; } } }'; }
```

3) You probably didn't `unalias` your previous attempt before you did your function attempt

```
unalias myip
```

After making those changes, the function should work without a syntax error.

Comment: and change your awk command to `awk '($1~/inet/) && (++count==2) {print $2}'` to be more idiomatic and concise.