# How is subshell called from sed replacement part? There is some deep magic going on

Tags: bash, sed

I need to call subcommand from sed replacement part to transform data. I didn't expect it to work at all, but it does, yet for very specific invocation there is some escaping problem or smth. I totally don't understand it, can someone advice?

Lets start with function definition:

```
$ function add() { echo "<${1}>"; }
$ export -f add
$ add a
<a>
```

easy. Now some replacements, proving that it works.

```
$ echo 'aaa bbb' | sed "s/\(.*\) \(.*\)/\1 $(add \\2)/"
aaa <bbb>
$ echo -e 'aaa bbb\nccc ddd' | sed "s/\(.*\) \(.*\)/\1 $(add \\2)/"
aaa <bbb>
ccc <ddd>
```

so in this replacement ^^ we consumed entire line, took 2 capturing groups, first printed as is, and called function with 2nd one. Works as expected. But what if we use builtin instead of function?

```
echo -e 'aaa bbb\nccc ddd' | sed "s/\(.*\) \(.*\)/\1 $(echo \<\\2\>)/"
aaa <bbb>
ccc <ddd>
```

work as well. So what about custom script?

```
$cat<<EOF > /tmp/e
#!/bin/bash

echo "<\${1}>";
EOF
$ chmod u+x /tmp/e
$ echo -e 'aaa bbb\nccc ddd' | sed "s/\(.*\) \(.*\)/\1 $(/tmp/e \\2)/"
aaa <bbb>
ccc <ddd>
```

Works! This is awesome. So lets move to some actual data:

```
$ isoDurationToMillis 0h:00m:00s.089
89
```

This ^^ is custom script, invoked as this it works. So we can finally call sed with this:

```
$ echo 'aaa 0h:00m:00s.089' | sed "s/\(.*\) \(.*\)/\1 $(isoDurationToMillis \\2)/"
date: invalid date ‘1970-01-01 \\2’
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
aaa
```

so in this case the invocation does NOT work. BUT it's not that `0h:00m:00s.089` ins't passed into script. It is, if I do `echo $1` it will be printed, but the invocation of that script is somewhat funny, and in another part of that script, where I actually need value of `$1` the \2 is substituted instead. Can someone explain?

Comment: Add `set -x` in front of your commands. No, it does not work.

Answer (score 2):

> How is subshell called from sed replacement part?

In the presented code subshell is called **before** sed is executed, replacing the `$(...)` by it's output. Just like `echo "$(add \\2)"`.

```
sed "s/\(.*\) \(.*\)/\1 $(add \\2)/"
```

becomes:

```
sed "s/\(.*\) \(.*\)/\1 <\2>/"
```

And then `sed` executes, replacing `\2`.

Notes: prefer `name() { }` to define functions, keyword `function` is for compatibility for ksh. There is no reason to `export -f add`, function `add` is executed in current shell during command substitution expansion.  Use `set -x` to debug your scripts. There is no magic. Researching quoting rules in shell, what is command substitution, how does double quotes differ from single quotes.

`sed` is not capable of executing commands. GNU `sed` has an *extension* `e` flag that you can use to execute a custom command. Note, that exporting a function is a Bash specific feature, in case your `$SHELL` is not bash, would be better to call shell explicitly. Overall, the following command has big quoting problems and is unsafe, can remove all your files on malicious input. The quoting problems fastly become an issue. I recommend against using `e` sed extension and use it only for fun.

```
add() { echo "<${1}>"; }
export -f add
sed 's/.*/add &/e'
sed 's/.*/bash -c "add \"\$@\"" -- &/e'
```

Overall, if you want to execute a command for every line of input, just use `bash` and read the input line by line https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 . If you want to do some real code with parsing, use `awk` or just move to something more like `python`.

Comment: Why should one "prefer" omitting the function keyword? Why not prefer to keep the function keyword and omit the parentheses instead, for instance? Is there a solid argument behind this advice, or is it simply personal preference?

Comment: Hi, did you try like browsing the net? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7917018/what-is-the-function-keyword-used-in-some-bash-scripts , https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/73750/difference-between-function-foo-and-foo , https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC2112 . And sadly bash-hackers.wiki.org is down and in the copy https://github.com/flokoe/bash-hackers-wiki the page that mentions `function` keyword as obsolete in bash is not readable https://github.com/rawiriblundell/wiki.bash-hackers.org/blob/main/scripting/obsolete.md . Overall my advice is, prefer POSIX compliance over ksh

Comment: That said, there is nothing inherently wrong with using `function name()`. For my code review if it would be a bash script, not a POSIX compatible script, I wouldn't care and approve.

Comment: I'd certainly _mention_ that in a code review, especially for a function like this that could otherwise be extracted and re-used in a plain `sh` script.  But it's not a must-fix item.

Comment: Fair enough. The tag does mention 'bash' rather than 'sh'. When working in bash specifically, I'd prefer including the function keyword for readability. And if the script is meant to be bash-exclusive rather than POSIX, I generally consider incompatible syntax a plus :p.

Comment: In `ksh`, there's actually a small difference between functions declared with the `function` keyword and those without. No such difference exists in `bash`; it supports `function` simply to facilitate executing existing `ksh` scripts without having to edit them. When writing code specifically for `bash`, there is no reason to use `function`.

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou portability is one of the most basic desirable attributes of all software (along with robustness, conciseness, and efficiency). Adding `function` reduces portability so don't use it.