# Why cannot I define an empty function in shell?

Tags: bash, shell

I am learning bash. I accidentally encounter a syntax error with empty function.

```
#!/bin/bash
# script name : empty_function.sh
function empty_func() {
}

bash empty_function.sh

empty_function.sh: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `}'
empty_function.sh: line 3: `}'
```

I suppose it is because of definition of an empty function.
 I would like to know Why I cannot define an empty function?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The [bash shell's grammar](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html#SHELL_GRAMMAR) simply doesn't allow empty functions. A function's grammar is:

```
  name () compound-command [redirection]
  function name [()] compound-command [redirection]
```

And in a compound command of the form:

```
{ list; }
```

`list` can't be empty. The closest you can get is to use a null statement or return:

```
function empty_func() {
    : 
}
```

or

```
function empty_func() {
    return
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Try this instead:

```
empty_func() {
  :
}
```